# partial intersection - multiple groups

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am not sure how to approach my problem, thus I haven't been able to see if it already exists (apologies in advance)

```
Group    Item
 A         1
 A         2
 A         3
 B         1
 B         3
 C         1
 D         2
 D         3
```

I want to know all combinations of groups that share more than X items (2 in this example). And I want to know which items they share.

**RESULT**:

```
A-B: 2 (item 1 and item 3)
A-D: 2 (item 2 and item 3)
```

The list of groups and items is really long and the maximum number of item matches across groups is probably not more than 3-5.

**NB** More than 2 groups can have shared items - e.g. A-B-E: 3
So it's not sufficient to only compare two groups at a time. I  need to compare all combination of groups.

**My thoughts**

1. *First round*: one pile of all groups - are at least two values shared amongst all?
2. *Second round*: All-1 group (all combinations)
3. *Third round*: All-2 groups (all combinations)

Untill I reach the comparison between only two groups (all combinations). 
However this seems super heavy performance-wise!! And I have no idea of how to do this.

What are your thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean when you say "illustrate" ? Are you looking for a way to display the result ?

Comment: Hi Joseph, 
Thanks for commenting! I just updated the description. - Most importantly I'm looking for a way to get my result, but suggestions on how to illustrate/display the results are also welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have additional information to restrict the search, I would just process all subsets (having size >= 2) of the set of unique groups.

For each subset, I would search the items belonging to all members of the set:

```
a = df['Group'].unique()
for cols in chain(*(combinations(a, i) for i in range(2, len(a) + 1))):
    vals = df['Item'].unique()
    for col in cols:
        vals = df.loc[(df.Group==col)&(df.Item.isin(vals)), 'Item'].unique()
    if len(vals) > 0: print(cols, vals)
```

it gives:

```
('A', 'B') [1 3]
('A', 'C') [1]
('A', 'D') [2 3]
('B', 'C') [1]
('B', 'D') [3]
('A', 'B', 'C') [1]
('A', 'B', 'D') [3]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would approach the problem, it may not be the most efficient way to deal with it, but it has the merit to be clear.

1. List for each group, all items possessed by the group.
2. Then for each pair of group, list all shared items (for instance, for all items of group A, check if it is an item of group B).
3. Check if the number of shared items is higher than your threshold `X`.

It's not an off-the-shelf function, but it should be rather easy (or at least a good exercise) to implement.

Have fun !

Comment: Thanks. As I mention I want the combination of groups. Thus there can also be a combination of 4 different groups that share 2 (or more) items, e.g. A-C-E-Q: 2 (item10, item30)
Do you have an idea of how I can expand my comparison to include 3, 4, perhaps 10 groups? My list is very long so I need an automated process

Comment: You could do it recursively, once you've got the result for groups A and B, you can  do the same process with `group A-B` taken as only one group, and `group C` on the other hand, that'll give you the shared items between groups A-B-C. But be aware that your complexity would skyrocket from `O(n^2)` to `O(n^N)` where `N` is the max length of the combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is new solution that will work with all combinations

Steps:

1. get dataframe "grouped" which groups/lists all groups the the item is in
2. from each row of grouped get all possible combinations of group which has some common items
3. from "grouped" dataframe count for each combination if there are 2 or more common items add that in dictionary

**Note**: It only loop through group combinations that has common items so if you have lots of groups its already filters out huge part of possible combinations that don't have common items

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations

d = {
    "Group": "A,A,A,B,B,C,D,D".split(","),
    "Item": [1,2,3,1,3,1,2,3]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

grouped = df.groupby("Item").apply(lambda x: list(x.Group))

all_combinations_with_common = [sorted(combinations(item, i)) for item in grouped 
                                    for i in range(2, len(item)) if len(item)>=2]
all_combinations_with_common = np.concatenate(all_combinations_with_common)

commons = {}
REPEAT_COUNT = 2
for comb in all_combinations_with_common:
    items = grouped.apply(lambda x: np.all(np.in1d(comb, x)))
    if sum(items)>=REPEAT_COUNT:
        commons["-".join(comb)] = grouped[items].index.values


display(commons)
```

**output**

```
{'A-B': array([1, 3]), 'A-D': array([2, 3])}
```

Comment: Thanks. There can be more combination of groups than only two, e.g. A-B-Q: 3 shared items
So in theory I need to compare all combination of groups (maybe 5 different groups share 2 items). It looks like your approach works on common items between only two groups and not 10?

Comment: @Sand please check by new solution

Comment: Thank you, it worked on my testset, but as I was afraid of, it couldn't run due to memory problems on the real data. 
I htink I'll have to compare only to groups at a time.

Comment: oh..., did you find a working solution, I think number of  combinations that has common items shouldn't be that high. I think some optimization can be done in this part ```sorted(combinations(item, i)) ``` this creates some duplication combinations. how many unique groups and items do you have?